# how to crossfade animation for two image together that play on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a crossfade animation for two image that overlap together that play on hover

```css
#cf {
  position: relative;
  height: 281px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="https://ansushop.ir/images/Device_Liquid/L_miss%20angel3.jpg"/>
  <img class="top" src="https://ansushop.ir/images/Ansu_Sanitizer2.jpg" />
</div>
```

but i want crossfading happen on scrolling not on hover , can any one explane for me how i can show cross fade animation on scroll, not on hover ?

Comment: Are you trying to do similar to lazy loading; when the content becomes visible, it animates?

Comment: Have a look at the [AOS library](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/tree/v2).

Comment: a picture like a first picture in this site https://www.glouglou.at/

Comment: A useful thing is intersectionObserver, you tell the system to let you know when an element comes into view and then you can start the animation. It's pretty straightforward to set up, see for example, [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// With jQuery
var iframe = $("#cf-iframe").get(0);
var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
$(iframeWindow).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollTop = iframeWindow.pageYOffset || iframeWindow.document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    $("img.top", iframeWindow.document).css("opacity", 1 - scrollTop / 1000);
});

    
// With Just JavaScript and No jQuery
var iframe = document.getElementById("cf-iframe");
var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
iframeWindow.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = iframeWindow.pageYOffset || iframeWindow.document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    iframeWindow.document.querySelector("img.top").opacity = 1 - scrollTop / 1000;
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#cf-iframe {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="cf-iframe" srcdoc='
  <style>
    #cf {
      position: relative;
      height: 281px;
      width: 450px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    body {
    margin:0;
    height:1300px;
    background-color:#fff;
    }
    #cf img {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="cf">
    <img class="bottom" src="https://ansushop.ir/images/Device_Liquid/L_miss%20angel3.jpg"/>
    <img class="top" src="https://ansushop.ir/images/Ansu_Sanitizer2.jpg" />
  </div>
'></iframe>
```

See a working example [here](https://jsbin.com/zaciyun/).